# Minecraft Texture not loading 1.7.10

Tags: java, textures, minecraft

I am coding my first Minecraft mod and I can' get my item to load the texture. I am very new to coding Minecraft mods and I am a bit confused. Here is the code for the base item:

```
     package com.danielroberts.firstmod.item;

     import com.danielroberts.firstmod.reference.Reference;
     import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
     import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;
     import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.IIconRegister;
     import net.minecraft.item.Item;
     import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

     public class item1 extends Item
         {
         public item1()
         {
             super();
         }

         @Override
         public String getUnlocalizedName()
         {
             return String.format("item.%s%s", Reference.MOD_ID.toLowerCase() + ":",          getUnwrappedUnlocilizedName(super.getUnlocalizedName()));
         }

         @Override
         public String getUnlocalizedName(ItemStack itemStack)
         {
             return String.format("item.%s%s", Reference.MOD_ID.toLowerCase() + ":", getUnwrappedUnlocilizedName(super.getUnlocalizedName()));
         }

        @Override
        @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
        public void registerIcons(IIconRegister iconRegister)
        {
            itemIcon = iconRegister.registerIcon(this.getUnlocalizedName().substring(this.getUnlocalizedName().indexOf(".") + 1));
        }


         protected String getUnwrappedUnlocilizedName(String unlocilizedName)
         {
             return unlocilizedName.substring(unlocilizedName.indexOf(".") + 1);
         }
     }
```

And this is the code of the actual item:

```
package com.danielroberts.firstmod.item;




public class ItemDiamondtwo extends item1
{
    public ItemDiamondtwo()
    {
        super();
        this.setUnlocalizedName("doubleDiamond");
        this.setMaxStackSize(64);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can say is that to register a texture for an item you'll want to call the setTextureName(modId+":"+itemName) function.

i.e. setTexture("firstmod:doublediamond");

which will make it look for: "assets/firstmod/textures/items/doublediamond.png" upon init.

Answer (score 0):

With this setup I would say you need to place the texture at 
assets/$Modid/textures/items/doubleDiamond.png
Note Uppercase and Lowercase matter!!! so if the name of the file is doublediamond.png It would not work

I know this because I have this setup to :p